# Atmospheric falloff for volumetric materials?

Tags: compositing-nodes, volumetrics

I have a scene with volumetric clouds, and would like to have atmospheric falloff on them using the *mist pass*, however, as you'll see in this simplified scene, that didn't work.

Here's the scene. As you can see, there are clouds at varying distances to the camera.

[image]

If I render out the *mist pass*, the clouds are not visible at all.

[image]

Which leads to "incorrect" results on the clouds when adding the *mist pass* to the render.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]